# Why do I see a database login dialog when I show my report?

Tags: sql, database, crystal-reports, report

I have created my report using my friend's laptop, but when I copied it to my laptop and tryied to show the report I see a database login dialog.

this is the project I've worked on it.

```
http://www.4shared.com/zip/ZWHy0zPrce/WindowsFormsApplication7.html
```

My database saved in Debug Folder.
I've used DataSet.WriteXml() Function for the report.

Please see it and modify it please.

Comment: Open the report and check the Database Source properties. Check if the database details on the rpt file are the same as on your pc.

Comment: Can you tell me please where I can find the properties exactly? Where should I press to show it?

Comment: open the report, On the Toolbox -> Right click Database Fields -> Set Datasource Location -> You database connection will appear. extend Properties and check if this database is available on your machine. 
YOu can also create a new version of the report and create a connection specifically pointing to you pc and not your friends.